# Article use in sentences with multiple "of" phrases

Tags: phrases, prepositions, articles, definite-articles

**Do you have any simple-to-follow rules for a case given subsequently?** When different options should be preferred?

**A**

The three-month period was chosen to limit **the** use of personalised data of study patients.

**B**

The three-month period was chosen to limit **the** use of **the** personalised data of study patients.

**C**

The three-month period was chosen to limit **the** use of **the** personalised data of **the** study patients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best options are:

1. to restructure your sentence so to avoid so many definite
   articles, and/or
2. to use the indefinite article if it does not substantially alter
   the meaning.

Three examples are as follows.

**D**

> The three-month period was chosen to limit the use of study patients'
> personalised data.

**E**

> The three-month period was chosen to limit using the personalised data of
> study patients.

**F**

> A three-month period was chosen to limit the use of personalised data
> of study patients.